# Why is my JQuery Masonry grid overlapping my title?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

My JQuery Masonry grid is overlapping my title.

```
<div name="top" id="container">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="item">
        <h3>1</h3>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h3>2</h3>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h3>3</h3>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h3>4</h3>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h3>5</h3>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#container {
position:relative;
left:28%;
width:69%;
}

.item {
width:200px;
float:left;
background: #fff;
}
```

In the head section:

```
<!--Jquery functions-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    // This block will be put in a separate file later on (JQuery.js)
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $container = $('#container');            
   //$container.imagesLoaded(function(){                    
      $container.masonry({
         itemSelector: '.item',
         isAnimated: true,
      });
   //});
});
</script>
// ...
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Should I always put the title before the div? Like this:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<div name="top" id="container">
```

Or am I missing something in my CSS for my title?

```
h2 {
color:#751D24;
font:5em 'open sans', sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing:-.05em;
line-height:.5em;
margin:3.5% 0 2%;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

So basically, what would be the best solution?

Comment: Just leave the title outside the masonry wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the title out of the `#container` as the Masonry plugin absolute positions the `.item` elements within the container you specify.

You can change the code like so:

**HTML**

```
<div name="top" id="container">
    <h2>Title</h2>

    <div id="masonry-container">
        <div class="item">
            <h3>1</h3>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var $container = $('#masonry-container');            
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){                    
    $container.masonry({
       itemSelector: '.item',
       isAnimated: true,
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you :) That's what I thought!

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark me as the answer :) Thanks.

Comment: There should be a tick to the left of my answer just below the up and down arrows. If you click it, it will mark it as the answer.